# How do I change the system color in justinmind prototyper?

Tags: prototype, justinmind

It's like I am designing a prototype in justinmind's prototyper and every time I decide to place a status bar or a section bar it keeps on giving me the default material design color.

I want to change the color scheme of the prototype itself, for example grey instead of material blue.

Is there a way I can do that either globally or locally?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Templates to define certain default styles of your widgets. Go to the template you are using for your screens, right-click on it (in the Templates panel list) and select 'Edit Template Style'. A dialog will show up and there you can define the default style for your widgets (e.g.: edit Rectangle background style for your status bar). After editing your template you can use the option 'Apply Template Style' to apply the changes to the already created elements in your screen.

Another options would be to create your own widget library. Go to menu 'Widgets' and select 'New widget library'. Then just build your own library with the styles you want dragging widgets and dropping them on the widgets panel.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the color of each widget/component of a prototype from the top toolbar or from the Properties tab.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The link takes to an image, it won´t let me embed it yet.